# android Websocket socket.io nullpointer

Tags: android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, socket.io

```
theButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

client = new SocketIOClient(URI.create("http://192.168.0.157:8080"), new SocketIOClient.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            Log.e("WS", "Connected!");
        }

        @Override
        public void on(String event, JSONArray arguments) {

        theButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            Log.e("WS", "Got event "+event+":"+arguments.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect(int code, String reason) {

            Log.e("WS", "Disconnected! Code: "+code+" Reason:"+reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception error) {
            Log.e("WS", "+++ Error +++"+error);
        }
    });

    client.connect();
```

The Problem is, if I Change the BackgroundColor in the Event Funktion I get a NullPointer exeption:

> E/AndroidRuntime(16409): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11864
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409):    at com.fritsch.cpu.SocketIOClient.cleanup(SocketIOClient.java:183)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409):    at com.fritsch.cpu.SocketIOClient.access$0(SocketIOClient.java:181)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409):    at com.fritsch.cpu.SocketIOClient$2.onError(SocketIOClient.java:152)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409):    at com.fritsch.cpu.WebSocketClient$1.run(WebSocketClient.java:125)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16409):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

If I change the BG Color after initial it works fine. I think the Problem is the Thread of the Websocket.

Comment: have you done `setContentView` before `findViewById`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can change UI in your thread, and I think you can try to use Handler to deal with the UI updating.